# Swap in raydium without pool keys

Tags: solana-program

Does anyone know if there is any way to do a SWAP between SOL and a specific token on Raydium without having to make a time-consuming request to the endpoint https://api.raydium.io/v2/sdk/liquidity/mainnet.json??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swap transaction with raydium](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/9136/swap-transaction-with-raydium)

Comment: you can use hellomoon.io to find pairs associated with SOL

Comment: @shackra Is there any specific method for this RPC that you recommend? I need to get into tokens that were launched just a few seconds ago. Do you recommend any method for this RPC to obtain the pool keys? Or what do you advise?

Comment: @Ericvinicius I'm working on the same kind of project. I just wrote the part that interacts with Jupiter Station in Node.JS using Typescript. Regarding your exact question…

Comment: If you want to see what are the new token pairs on Raydium, you can create a websocket subscription in hellomoon.io with the event stream LP creation (see [docs](https://docs.hellomoon.io/docs/lp-creations))

Comment: Does this datasource provide enough information to perform a swap transaction?

Comment: @Ericvinicius no, you use the mints and do the swap with jup.ag

Answer (score 0):

You can manually build up instruction and then proceed to add them to your transaction. This [gist](https://gist.github.com/endrsmar/684c336c3729ec4472b2f337c50c3cdb) achieves this perfectly. I'm working on a python version